# Getting error: override method should call super.onActivityResult

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to capture an image from the camera and display it on the imageView. I tried but getting the error "override method should call super.onActivityResult", you can see my code below. Please let me know if I am doing it right.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try{
            val file= File(currentPath)
            val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)

            val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
            imageView.setImageURI(uri)
        }catch(e:IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == PICK_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try{
            val uri = data!!.data

            val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
            imageView.setImageURI(uri)
        }catch(e:IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add `super.onActivityResult(...)` at the beginning of your onActivityResult method. It's telling it to you right there: "overriding method **must** call super.."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` as first line on the `onActivityResult` method.

Answer (score 4):

### What does it mean?

When a class extends another, say you have `class A` and `class B : A`

In this context, class A is the `super` class of B.

So if class `A` has a method called:

`fun someMethod()`

you can do:

```
var myB = B()
myB.someMethod()
```

this effectively calls the code in A, because B extends A, and `someMethod` is not private.

Now if you want to modify `someMethod`'s behavior in B, you `override` it...

```
override fun someMethod() {
   // b does something different here
}
```

now, you can mark A's `someMethod` as `@CallSuper` (an annotation coming from [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations).

In which case you get the warning/error that B must call its super (know as Parent too) class too...

so B must now do:

```
override fun someMethod() {
   super.someMethod()
   // your B code too..
}
```

There's no rule to call it *at the beginning* you can call it at any time, as long as you do before the end of the function. In some instances, it's desired to call it as the first thing (if, for instance, A does something you need in B as well), and in some other cases, you want to wait for B to do something before calling `super...`. As long as you do.

`onActivityResult` is marked as such, and therefore you **must** call super.